# How to check the conditions and save files by using in one .csv file in C#

Tags: c#, csv

I have a `.csv` file. I want to create files by using this file. This is format of the `.csv` file. This is a small part of my `.csv` file. I have 60000 more rows in my original file.

```
Date,Pass,CutMark1,Marks1,CutMark2,Marks2,
22/06/2017 13:04:18,FALSE,TRUE,40,FALSE,35,
22/06/2017 13:04:20,FALSE,TRUE,35,FALSE,35,
22/06/2017 13:04:35,FALSE,TRUE,55,FALSE,55,
22/06/2017 13:04:37,FALSE,TRUE,100,FALSE,55,
22/06/2017 13:04:37,FALSE,TRUE,38,FALSE,55,
22/06/2017 13:04:38,FALSE,FALSE,35,FALSE,55,
22/06/2017 13:04:39,FALSE,FALSE,35,FALSE,38,
22/06/2017 13:04:40,FALSE,FALSE,35,TRUE,38,
22/06/2017 13:04:41,FALSE,FALSE,55,TRUE,38,
22/06/2017 13:04:42,FALSE,FALSE,55,TRUE,55,
22/06/2017 13:04:44,FALSE,FALSE,38,TRUE,55,
22/06/2017 13:04:45,TRUE,FALSE,38,TRUE,40,
22/06/2017 13:04:46,TRUE,FALSE,38,TRUE,40,
22/06/2017 13:04:48,TRUE,FALSE,55,FALSE,40,
22/06/2017 13:04:49,TRUE,FALSE,55,FALSE,25,
22/06/2017 13:04:50,TRUE,FALSE,55,FALSE,45,
22/06/2017 13:04:52,FALSE,TRUE,55,FALSE,60,
22/06/2017 13:04:53,FALSE,TRUE,40,FALSE,80,
22/06/2017 13:04:54,FALSE,TRUE,40,FALSE,80,
22/06/2017 13:04:56,FALSE,TRUE,40,FALSE,75,
22/06/2017 13:04:57,FALSE,TRUE,40,FALSE,90,
22/06/2017 13:04:58,FALSE,TRUE,55,FALSE,88,
22/06/2017 13:05:00,TRUE,TRUE,55,TRUE,23,
22/06/2017 13:05:01,TRUE,TRUE,55,TRUE,45,
22/06/2017 13:05:02,TRUE,TRUE,20,TRUE,78,
22/06/2017 13:05:04,TRUE,TRUE,45,TRUE,45,
22/06/2017 13:05:05,TRUE,TRUE,85,TRUE,69,
22/06/2017 13:05:06,TRUE,TRUE,62,TRUE,45,
22/06/2017 13:05:08,TRUE,TRUE,100,TRUE,35,
```

I want to save this files as follows. In here "Pass" column want to check. There is False then True after that False then again True and etc So I want to save files by using this. As an example I want to save this file first meet False values as False1.csv then secondly True1.csv then again meet False2.csv like that I want to add numbers into the file name which that True or False meet in how many times. I want that rows save particular all other column in this `.csv`file.

I use this example for explain for me, I want to save first all false and true values in different files. I get this  example for that. In here first 11 rows of Pass column is "False". So I want to save those (1-11 )rows in one file should save as `False1.csv`, then meet pass "True" there are rows (12-16) should save as `True1.csv`, then Pass value has again meet "False" then save those rows(17-22) as `False2.csv` again meet pass column is "True" then that rows(23-29) save as `True2.csv`, likewise I want to save, I have 60000 raws in my `.csv` file.

This is my code for reading the `.csv` file.

```
using System.Globalization;

public static string dateFormatString = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";

private void btnSeperateFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (tbOutputFilePath2 != null)
    {
        List<DrawNew> ObservingData = new List<DrawNew>(); // List to store all available DrawNew objects from the CSV

        // Loops through each lines in the CSV
        foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(outputFilePath.Text).Skip(1)) // .Skip(1) is for skipping header
        {
            string[] valuesCsvLine = line.Split(',');
            DrawNew mngInstance = new DrawNew();

            mngInstance.Date = DateTime.ParseExact(valuesCsvLine[0], dateFormatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 
            mngInstance.Pass = (valuesCsvLine[1] == "TRUE" ? true : false);
            mngInstance.CutMark1 = (valuesCsvLine[2] == "TRUE" ?true: false);
            mngInstance.Marks1 = int.Parse(valuesCsvLine[3]);                 
            mngInstance.CutMark2 = (valuesCsvLine[4] == "TRUE" ? true : false);
            mngInstance.Marks2 = int.Parse(valuesCsvLine[5]); 

            ObserveData.Add(mngInstance);
        }            
    }
}
```

This is the class for storing data of `.csv` file:

```
class DrawNew
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; } // property to store Date 
    public bool Pass { get; set; } // property to store Pass
    public bool CutMark1 { get; set; } // property to store CutMark1
    public int Marks1 { get; set; } // property to store Marks1
    public bool CutMark2 { get; set; } // property to store CutMark2
    public int Marks2 { get; set; } // property to store Marks2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best or most performant or even nicest way to do it, but it might get you started:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;

[...]

public void StoreSeparatedByPass(IEnumerable<DrawNew> observingData)
{
  // keep the file numbers easily accessible
  var fileCounts
    = new Dictionary<bool, int>
      {
        { false, 0 },
        { true, 0 }
      };

  bool? pass = null;
  var lines = new List<DrawNew>();

  foreach (var drawNew in observingData)
  {
    // to differentiate between "starting with false" 
    // and "starting with true".
    // (only interesting on first item)
    if (pass.HasValue == false)
    {
      pass = drawNew.Pass;
    }

    if (pass.Value != drawNew.Pass)
    {
      // the value of drawNew.Pass changed, the previous "part" has ended.
      // now we need to do store the collected lines (if there are any)...
      if (lines.Any())
      {
        fileCounts[pass.Value]++;
        StoreLines(lines, pass.Value.ToString() + fileCounts[pass.Value] + ".csv");

        // then clear the stored list for the next part...
        lines.Clear();
      }

      // and change the part indicator.
      pass = drawNew.Pass;
    }

    lines.Add(drawNew);
  }

  // don't forget to store the last part...
  if (pass.HasValue && lines.Any())
  {
    fileCounts[pass.Value]++;
    StoreLines(lines, pass.Value.ToString() + fileCounts[pass.Value] + ".csv");
  }
}
public void StoreLines(IEnumerable<DrawNew> lines, string fileName)
{
  // TODO: actually write the DrawNew items to the given filename
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.Can you say how to write to transfer the column headers to save that files.

Comment: Easiest way would be to get and remember the first line of the original file (the one you skip over) and write that as first line to all the new files (in `StoreLines`)